# how to use apache for serving PHP and use nginx for static pages

Tags: php, linux, webserver

I buy a VPS and i want to configure it. I read somewhere:
**You could mix them both. Use Apache for serving PHP and use nginx for static pages**

My OS is linux-ubuntu. Now i want to know how can i do this ?

how say to my dynamic code that use Apache web server and static code use Nginx web server. anybody can help me ?

Regards

Comment: Thi is **way** too broad for SO (and probably any other Q&A-site), and I'm sure Google knows many great tutorials on how to do that.

Comment: if fact before asking here, i google it and couldn't learn it ..!

Comment: Ok, maybe you just used the wrong keywords. Just search for something like "apache with nginx proxy" and you'll get tons of material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to let one of them being the front end that listens to port 80, and the other one to listen to some other port (say 8080), since it is not possible to have more than one process listening to the same port. The one that listens to port 80 must then be set up to forward traffic to the one listening to the alternative port.

It is most natural to let the one serving static pages (nginx) to do the port forwarding in that case. To do that, put a server definition like this in the html section of nginx.conf:

```
server{
   listen 80;
   server_name example.com;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

   location /php {
       proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080/;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

This will forward all urls that start with /php/ to the root at your apache server running at port 8080 (If you want another change the proxy_pass setting).

That said, in order to make things simpler, I would prefer to only run one server, sticking with either apache or nginx. Both servers can serve both of these roles.

You may want to either disable the default configuration or modify it to include the config above, since you will get a port conflict otherwise.